# Delete newline characters between patterns

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, perl

```
foo
I love
Stack Exchange
bar
Some junk
lines
foo
Welcome to the
world of
Bash
bar
foo
Elon Musk
rocks
```

Yes, there is no `bar` complementing `foo` at the end of the file

The required output is

```
I love Stack Exchange
Welcome to the world of Bash
Elon Musk rocks
```

So, remove all newline characters, between `^foo` and `^bar` or between `^foo` and the `end of file` where there is no `bar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk '
  $0 == "foo" {if (sep) print ""; sep = ""; inside = 1; next}
  $0 == "bar" {inside = 0; next}
  inside {printf "%s", sep $0; sep = " "}
  END {if (sep) print ""}'
```

To match on lines with `foo` as the first word, replace `$0 == "foo"` with `$1 == "foo"`; to match on lines starting with `foo`, replace with `/^foo/` (short for `$0 ~ /^foo/`).

Answer (score 2):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -ne '
    if ($e = /^foo$/ .. /^bar$/) {
        if ($e =~ /E/) { print "\n" }
        else {
            chomp;
            print " " if $e > 2;
            print     if $e > 1;
        }
}' -- input.txt
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line
- `..` is the range operator, it returns the relative line number for each line in a block. The last line has `E0` appended to it.

Comment: Why are `>2` and `>1` used here and what are they doing basically?

Comment: It's numerical comparison. `$e > 2` excludes the first two lines of each block, `$e > 1` excludes only the first (foo) one.

Comment: Yes, you can move the `$e > 1` one level up: `perl -ne 'if ($e = /^foo$/ .. /^bar$/) { if ($e =~ /E/) { print "\n" } elsif ($e > 1) { chomp; print " " if $e > 2; print; } }' -- file`

Answer (score 1):

You could do this way also:

a) This is `POSIX-sed` compliant code wherein we store the mid-range lines (!/foo/ and !/bar/) in the hold area.

```
sed -e '
    /foo/,/bar/!d
    /foo/d
    /bar/!{H;$!d;}
    s/.*//;x;s/^\n//;y/\n/ /
' input-file.txt
```

b) and with `Perl` as shown

```
perl -lne '
   next unless /foo/ ... /bar/;
   push(@A, $_),next if !/foo/ && !/bar/ && !eof;
   push(@A, $_)      if !/foo/ && !/bar/ &&  eof;
   print join " ", splice @A if /bar/ || !/foo/ && eof;
' input-file.txt
```

**Explanation:**

- skip non-interesting lines or lines that fall out of range. A range is defined as beginning with a line containing `/foo/` and ending with `/bar/`, both occurring on separate lines.
- Once we are in the range, then perform separate actions based on what line we are in.
- For lines that are not /foo/, neither /bar/, and neither eof : store the line in the array `@A`. After storing, go back for reading the next record provided not eof.
- Only for the end of range, i.e., `/bar/` or `eof`, we take the action of printing what's in `@A` and also emptying it, in preparation for the next gathering cycle.